# python find matches between two list of n by 1 numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

It's been a while I am looking for the solution of a probleme of this type:
For instance(because my real problem is more complex) :

```
import numpy

a=[numpy.array([1,2]),numpy.array([2,2]),numpy.array([3,2]),numpy.array([4,2])]
b=[numpy.array([2,2]),numpy.array([3,2]),numpy.array([6,2]),numpy.array([5,2]),numpy.array([5,2])]

ya=numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
size_a=len(a)
size_b=len(b)
yb=numpy.empty((size_b,1))
yb.fill(numpy.nan)

for i in xrange(size_b):
    for j in xrange(size_a):
        if numpy.array_equiv(yb,ya):
            ya[i]=yb[j]
```

I just want to fill yb with the ya value of the index of a element matching one element of b. As yb is longer than ya, it's normal that yb will contain "nan" at the end of the loops.
The code below takes a too long time to proceed. In fact I don't know if it works because I hadn't wait for the end of the loops...

In the real case, ya and yb are longer: 7007 and 3525

Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Could you check through your code for syntax errors? Get it to a stage where you can paste it into a .py file and run it as is

Comment: I think this question in some form or another has been asked quite a few times. You can (and with your sizes if you care about speed, should) solve this with sorting based approaches too.

Answer (score 1):

To find matches between lists of arrays, the most straightforward method is to broadcast the lists to the same `n x m` shape; this can be done with `np.tile` but using `stride_tricks` is faster:

```
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
shape = (2, a.shape[0], b.shape[0])
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
a = as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=(a.strides[1], a.strides[0], 0))
b = as_strided(b, shape=shape, strides=(b.strides[1], 0, b.strides[0]))
np.where(np.all(a == b, axis=0))
```

This gives the result

```
(array([1, 2]), array([0, 1]))
```

i.e. `a[1] == b[0]`, and `a[2] == b[1]`, with no other matches.

Comment: Thank's for the rapid answer!:) I will test it soon!

Comment: If you got a big enough hammer, everything looks like a nail ;). No need for stride tricks, simple reshaping/indexing with None + broadcasting does the trick too.